# How to get data from resolve in another controller?

Tags: angularjs

I use routing in Angular JS with `resolve` function:

```
.when("/:type/:user/:id", {
                        template: " ",
                        controller: "AppController",
                        resolve: {
                            "myVar": function (appService) {
                                return appService.get({type : "5"}).then(function (response) {
                                    return response.app;
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    })
```

At controller `AppController` I have:

```
.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$http', '$route', '$sce', 'appService', 'myVar', function ($scope, $http, $route, $sce, appService, myVar) {
            $scope.app = myVar;
        }])
```

Also I have another controller:

```
.controller('SecondController', ['$scope', '$http', '$route', '$sce', 'appService', function ($scope, $http, $route, $sce, appService) {

    // Get here $scope.app from first controller

}])
```

I use `service` for this:

```
.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$http', '$route', '$sce', 'appService', 'myVar', function ($scope, $http, $route, $sce, appService, myVar) {
   appService._set(myVar);
}])


.controller('SecondController', ['$scope', '$http', '$route', '$sce', 'appService', function ($scope, $http, $route, $sce, appService) {
   $scope.app = appService._get();
}])
```

When I try to get data in controller `SecondController` via service:

```
$scope.app = appService._get();
console.log($scope.app);
```

I get undefined message in console

Comment: does `AppController` & `SecondController` are nested?

Comment: I have only `SecondController` in HTML code

Comment: Can't you set the value on  `appService` within the resolve?

Comment: I can, but problem in controller, because I get result in controller

Comment: create a simple demo. If both controllers  are in same route should be easy to use resolve to also set the service data

Comment: If you know about priority of loading and asynchrony in Angular JS, you understand me

Comment: in resolve I use another controller, not `SecondController`, because `SecondController` I want to use in template

Comment: see this example using `resolve` to set data in service  http://plnkr.co/edit/6Gps3s6gHBZIjUFxzgK1?p=preview

Comment: Thank you will try, may I not use `<ng-view></ng-view>`?

Comment: `<ng-view>` is in that demo

Comment: It works unstable, I get at first empty `console.log` `model.name` after with data. So my controller is called twice

Comment: update demo and fork it

Comment: Seem I know problem, I use empty `template: " "` in routing and dont use `ng-view`. May I can not use this?

Comment: When I have some `ng-view` at page I get content everewhere, how I can fix it that content is loaded only for routing and controller `AppController`?